# SQL Create dates between date range for multiple dimensions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ServLine,RoomID,StartDt,EndDt
INTO    #raw
FROM    table

SELECT  CALENDAR_DATE
INTO    #cal
FROM    caldendar
```

How would I write a query to show each CALENDAR_DATE from the #cal table that is in between each StartDt and EndDt for each RoomID and ServLine from the #raw table.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a join. Depending on exactly what input and desired output you have, the join may vary, but an `inner join` seems like a good place to start without more information.

```
select *
from #raw r
  inner join #cal c
    on c.date >= r.startdt
   and c.date <= r.enddt
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe it was that easy. Thanks!

Comment: You could use `c.date BETWEEN r.startdt AND r.enddt` as well

Comment: @EMUEVIL Be careful with `between`, it might not match expectations. [What do `between` and the devil have in common? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: @SqlZim Good point.  I've had problems before where the first expression is greater than the second and it didn't work.